# Automatic reordering of a Vector using Melt() in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a very simple set of side-by-side barplots using ggplot. I've been successful in rendering the plots using this code:

```
Snowmobile_Status = c("Never Used","Snowmobile Renter","Snowmobile Owner")
No = c(445,497,279)
Yes = c(212,77,16)
SnowMobilers <- data.frame(Snowmobile_Status,No,Yes)
SnowMobilers.long<-melt(SnowMobilers)
ggplot(SnowMobilers.long,aes(Snowmobile_Status,value,fill=variable))+
    geom_bar(color="black",stat="identity",position="dodge")+
    ggtitle("Environmental Club Membership\nRelative to Snow Mobile Ownership") + 
    ylab("Frequency") +        
    xlab("Snowmobile Status") + 
    scale_fill_grey()
```

However, my output bar plot has reordered the columns in Snowmobile_Status from

```
"Never Used","Snowmobile Renter","Snowmobile Owner"
```

to

```
"Never Used","Snowmobile Owner","Snowmobile Renter"
```

I really would like to maintain the original order. I gather that I need to factor this vector manually to avoid reordering, but I'm struggling to make this work in conjunction with melt().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the levels of the factor prior to melting, they will stay the same.  So, when you make your `SnowMobilers` data.frame, set the levels

```
SnowMobilers <- data.frame(
    Snowmobile_Status=factor(Snowmobile_Status, levels=Snowmobile_Status),
    No,
    Yes
)
```

Otherwise, the levels are ordered alphabetically by default.